# Javascript array assigning index value is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, web

I am facing this issue, [image]console output contains 3 arrays, the first is on top (contains ids), the second is which contains the movies name based on that id, the third contains the movie poster, so the main thing is tag [11] before the first string that the other two arrays don't have [11], although there are 11 11 items in them. SO due to this, I am unable to fetch the first index i.e. titles[0] give an error while first array ids[0] give the first element. How I can overcome this issue

I also marked the output thanks
Do not know how to deal with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
        <div id="pred">
    
    
        </div>
    
    
        <script>
            let ids = "[19995, 440, 679, 17663, 602, 7450, 44943, 34851, 11551, 76757, 11260]"
            
            let data = JSON.parse(ids.replaceAll("\""))
            console.log(data)
            let titles = []
            let posters = []
            
            my_api_key = '34b55fa7f2d2346aa1045ed4cc22bd12'
            url1 = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'
            url2 = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" 
            for(i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
             url = url1 + data[i] + '?api_key=' + my_api_key;
            
            fetch(url).then((data)=>{
                return data.json();
            
            }).then((completedata)=>{
                titles.push(completedata.title);
                posters.push(url2 + (completedata.poster_path));
            
            }).catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
            
            }
            let my_M = "";
            my_M = `
            <h1 style="color:blue ;">
                    <span>${titles[0]}</span>
            </h1>
            `;
            document.getElementById("pred").innerHTML = my_M;
            
            console.log(titles)
            console.log(posters)
            </script>
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear: what are you trying to achieve ? What are your 'arrays' ? I see a string `ids`, then `data` wich is a json object, then `titles` and `posters` which are arrays. Maybe you can use the snippet function to make a runnable javacsript example.

Comment: The result arrays most likely print before they have been filled with the results from the API calls. Underlying reason is that your code runs asynchronously, ie. no guarantes for the relative execution order of the `fetch` callback and the other script portion. Synchronize with `await`, Promises or similar mechanisms

Comment: also, I highly advise against including tags through `innerHTML` as this can be used as an injection for XSS attacks. `insertAdjacentHTML` will be more secure and execute way faster as it requires far fewer resources. As long as you only include tags like your markup, you should use `createElement` and append.

Comment: Dear Nicolas Moreau! Thanks for your time;
console output contains 3 arrays, the first is on top (contains ids), the second is which contains the movies name based on that id, third contains the movie poster, so the main thing is tag [11] before the first string that the other two arrays don't have [11], although there are 11 11 items in them. SO due to this, I am unable to fetch the first index i.e. titles[0] give an error while first array ids[0] give the first element. How I can overcome this issue
I hope now it is cleared

Comment: This is an async issue. Your code to complete titles and posters isnt finished by the time this piece `<span>${titles[0]}</span>` of code runs

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the `{}` as return for the last two `console.log()` is because your API fetch is not finished when you code reaches the `console.log(titles)`
and `console.log(posters)` in the end. So the data which is coming after the fetch (inside then) is not yet available. This is called synchronously running code.

To make sure that the latter piece of code will 'wait' for the earlier piece we need to make the code asynchronously, you can read more about it in this [article](https://www.codingem.com/javascript-promises-in-for-loops/#:%7E:text=Artturi%20Jalli-,To%20use%20Javascript%20promises%20in,loop%2C%20use%20async%20%2F%20await%20.&text=This%20waits%20for%20each%20promiseAction,next%20iteration%20in%20the%20loop.&text=In%20this%20guide%2C%20you%20learn,using%20promises%20in%20for%20loops.).

I am not quit sure what you are trying to achieve but if you  you would get something like below for your javascript code.

EDIT: I added the .then(()=>{}) to make sure the list on rendered after the element is created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<div id="pred">


</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    const ids = [19995, 440, 679, 17663, 602, 7450, 44943, 34851, 11551, 76757, 11260]
    console.log(ids)
    let titles = []
    let posters = []
    my_api_key = '34b55fa7f2d2346aa1045ed4cc22bd12'
    url1 = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'
    url2 = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"
    const fetchData = url =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
                fetch(url).then((data) => {
                    return data.json();
                }).then((completedata) => {
                    titles.push(completedata.title);
                    posters.push(url2 + (completedata.poster_path));
                    resolve(url)
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        );

    const fetchAllData = async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            let url = url1 + ids[i] + '?api_key=' + my_api_key;
            await fetchData(url);
        }
        console.log('All data is fetched');
    };
    fetchAllData().then(() => {
        let my_M = "";
        my_M = `
            <h1 style="color:blue ;">
                    <span>${titles[0]}</span>
            </h1>
            `;
        document.getElementById("pred").innerHTML = my_M;
        console.log(titles[0], posters)
    });


</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but your function is also working as same as my code was working, e.g., console output contains 3 arrays, first are on top (contains ids), second is which contains movies name based on that id, third contains movie poster, so the main thing is tag [11] before first string that others two arrays don't have [11], although there are 11 11 items in them. SO due to this, I am unable to fetch the first index i.e. titles[0] give an error while first array ids[0] give the first element. How I can overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to access the titles before receiving the response from the API. In javascript we call it asynchronous code. You can make your code synchronous by waiting for its execution to finish. You can use async/await syntax to deal with this.

You can try running the below code snippet. You will see some delay on the console log.

Your fetch request API call is awaited using `await`. In order for you to use await inside a function, you need to add `async keyword on the function`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
        <div id="pred">
    
    
        </div>
    
    
        <script>
        async function fetchMoviesJSON(url) {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const movies = await response.json();
            return movies;
        }
        
        async function fetchTitles() {
            let ids = "[19995, 440, 679, 17663, 602, 7450, 44943,                             34851, 11551, 76757, 11260]";
            
            let data = JSON.parse(ids.replaceAll("\""));

            let titles = [];
            let posters = [];
            
            const my_api_key = '34b55fa7f2d2346aa1045ed4cc22bd12';
            const url1 = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
            const url2 = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" ;
            for (i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
                url = url1 + data[i] + '?api_key=' + my_api_key;
                try {
                  const movieResponse = await fetchMoviesJSON(url);
                  titles.push(movieResponse.title);
                  posters.push(url2 + (movieResponse.poster_path));
                } catch (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
                const my_M = `
                <h1 style="color:blue ;">
                        <span>${titles[0]}</span>
                </h1>
                `;
                document.getElementById("pred").innerHTML = my_M;
            }
            console.log(titles);
            console.log(posters)
        }
        fetchTitles()
      </script>
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "subodhkalika", 
This method works